# how to use Multi-Level-Sidebar-Menu-HC-MobileNav in React?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Hi I want to implement (https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Multi-Level-Sidebar-Menu-HC-MobileNav.html) jQuery script for navbar in my react app but when I search for how to implement jquery plugins in react app the solutions are just very confusing , can anybody please tell me how to implement it simply ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you'll ever get React and this jQuery plugin to play nicely together. It is possible to run jQuery plugins inside of React apps, but the solutions (as you've noticed) aren't usually straightforward. It usually means telling React to ignore the section of the page that the jQuery plugin is controlling (the sidebar menu, in this case).

The underlying cause of this is that React works by controlling the DOM for you. As the state and props change, React re-computes what the DOM elements should be and then modifies the DOM tree to match. This is opposed to jQuery's model which allows direct manipulation of the DOM. When the DOM is modified from outside of React (by a jQuery plugin, for example), this causes React to lose track of the DOM's state and usually causes React throw an error ("Invariant Violation") and quit. Basically, you can't have React and jQuery both making changes to the same part of the page -- they'll conflict with each other.

The best course of action is probably to find a menu component written purely in React and abandon the jQuery plugin. There's a list of reasonable options here: https://reactjsexample.com/tag/menu/